# Ruby on Rails strange requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I´m checking my Ruby on Rails log files and I wonder why do I have request like this one (my app doesn´t have any request like this):

```
I, [2015-07-13T11:45:26.004933 #22638]  INFO -- : Started GET "/Ringing.at.your.dorbell!" for 186.116.51.54 at 2015-07-13 11:45:26 +0000
F, [2015-07-13T11:45:26.005954 #22638] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/Ringing.at.your.dorbell!"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:74:in `call'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/server.rb:490:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/server.rb:361:in `process_client'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:96:in `call'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:96:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Some n00b trying to be slick.  Honestly, they may be trying to poke and prod at the website's security to see if it can be compromised.

Comment: Someone attempted to navigate to URL `www.yourdomain.com/Ringing.at.your.dorbell!`.

Comment: should I do anything special?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just looks like someone is poking your system with a script, or just poking to see if that URL exists.  Have you double checked that you're serving up the proper `404` response?

Comment: If I do www.mydomain.com/Ring.at.your.doorbell I´m redirecting to my home.

Comment: @Rober That is an appropriate response.  You could also serve up your own 404 page, but it doesn't look like something you should worry about.